# mat-flat-button color is getting changed once it is clicked and coming back to normal color only after a blur event

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I am having a button that is mat-flat-button with background color as light blue. When it is clicked, some popup will come as per my requirement. I observed that the button's background color is getting darken once I clicked. Once I closed that popup, the mat-flat-button's background color has to come into normal color which is light blue. But, that is not happening and the button's background color is still in darken mode. That normal background color is coming to normal light blue color only if I performed a mouse blue event. Why this is happening for mat-flat-button? I am new to Angular and I tried lot to resolve this with no luck. Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is come from material design. You have more status. Have focus, hover, active (etc..) status. This background color indicates the active focused element. When you click the button, and the dialog opened the focus moves to the dialog, and when the dialog is closed the focus return to the button. This is why your button works so wierd. This background color comes from the theme colors. You can change this behavior whit some css rules.